# How to write a file that take newline and indentation properly in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to write a content to a file `model.yml` in a proper indentation and new line as the given content, but after writing a file,  those new line character like '\n' and '\t' were still visible and the content did not take new line and indentation as properly as the given content to write.

```
>>> content = """
... REGISTER_DE:
... - DescriptionArea:
...   - label: Hello Description
...   - type: String
...   - length: Long
...   - required: False
... - Field3:
...   - label: Date Field
...   - type: Date
... - Field4:
...   - type: TextAreaField
...   - required: True
... - Field5:
...   - type: String
...   - length: Medium"""
>>> file = open('model.yml', 'w+')
>>> file.write(content)
```

**model.yml**

```
"\nREGISTER_DE:\n- DescriptionArea:\n  - label: Hello Description\n  - type: String\n\
  \  - length: Long\n  - required: False\n- Field3:\n  - label: Date Field\n  - type:\
  \ Date\n- Field4:\n  - type: TextAreaField\n  - required: True\n- Field5:\n  - type:\
  \ String\n  - length: Medium"
```

How can I write the content to `model.yml` to take newline and indentation properly? It should be like this:

```
REGISTER_DE:
- DescriptionArea:
  - label: Hello Description
  - type: String
  - length: Long
  - required: False
- Field3:
  - label: Date Field
  - type: Date
- Field4:
  - type: TextAreaField
  - required: True
- Field5:
  - type: String
  - length: Medium
```

Thanks

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: @Frodon, to my badness, I run script directly from the terminal console it resulted as above, but if I run from python file instead, it worked fine. thanks

Comment: It worked also fine in the terminal